# Are screenshots and other images on askubuntu.com free to be used?

Tags: discussion

While looking for information on hindi keyboard, I found really nice keyboard images on that page:
[How to type the Devanagari tra letter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573667/how-to-type-the-devanagari-tra-letter)
Are these images under Creative Commons licence? Can I use them in another context? Or, to whom should I ask permission to use these images?
(In my case, it would be in an educative context, for a school report)

Thank you for attention!

Comment: Besides what is legal: you can make these from your own system. Using images from your own desktop is always allowed.